# Isn't virtual machine quite a type of process?

Tags: virtual-machine

I'm trying to understand the basic concepts of Docker, and lots of docs say that "Docker is not virtual machine, but a process". To me, this sentence looks quite awkward, since as far as I know, virtual machine it self also runs on host os, which makes itself a 'Process'.

Is there any big difference between the way the virtual machine works and the other normal applications/process do?

Comment: Say every VM is a process, but not every process is a VM.

Comment: Virtual machine is using hypervisor functionality. Guest has its own kernel. Host OS traps guest instructions, could be hardware supported. Containers OTOH makes use of host kernel features (cgroups, namespace). This puts a restriction that you can only run container images of same OS as host. You can' t run linux container on a windows host as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker is a brand name of a container management software system.
TL;DR:

1. **Containers are a packaging concept.**
2. **VMs are a compatibility concept.**
3. **VMs are a security concept.**

A container is not a process, it is an isolation of a collection of processes within a *single-system-image.*  What is isolated?  First, and foremost, the *path name space*.  Processes within a given container share a *path name space*, so that they agree that /usr/bin/env is the same thing.  Two processes in different containers, or perhaps inside the non-containered environment, would not necessarily see the same file for /usr/bin/env.   This functionality has been a feature of UNIX derived systems for at least 40 years; under the service *chroot()*.

More recently, containers have taken to isolate things that are not in the namespace, like processes, user ids and network interfaces.  In older chroot-based systems, running *ps* in a container would show processes that were not in that container; although special handling hacked into to prevent a chrooted root user from gaining root access on the underlying system.

In these modern systems, not only is the *pid space* partitioned, but also *user ids*, so that root in a container does not correspond to root on the overall system.

All this is accomplished by controlling many features of the kernel in a single-system-image.   The software that controls these features:  Docker, amongst others.

A Virtual Machine is not part of a single-system-image.   Each VM is its own logical computer, running its own kernel, shell, etc..   With some careful configuration, you can make it so various files appear within many of the VMs; but that is no different than mounting file systems exported by a network file system.

Why choose one over the other: containers share my os, and are handy to escape the *.so verionitis hell* caused by conflicting software systems; I can package my software in a container, and it is isolated from whatever the running system is.   I cannot, however, package the kernel I need; so if my software requires ubuntu 14.02; and I am running 18.04, containers will not save me.  **Containers are a packaging concept.**

VMs are handy to support multiple versions or types of operating systems in a single computer.  Since each VM runs unique system software, I can run my 14.02 app on my 18.04 system and none is the wiser.  **VMs are a compatibility concept.**

VMs are also handy as a security layer.  Imagine that a web page has a js-bomb that can corrupt my kernel (I know, quite a stretch).  If I run my browser in a container, I have corrupted my kernel.  If I run it in a VM, I have corrupted that VMs kernel -- I merely have to delete it, or rewind it, and the corruption is gone. **VMs are a security concept.**